# How to make a notch like google pay in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I'm trying to develop a similar UI of Google pay, you can find the reference image below

[image: This is a random image from Google search]

(That notch kind of part near to **Pay** logo)

but I don't know how to achieve it, please someone give a reference or code to create this

I have a layout till that blue part with a chart inside it, now I need to develop below part like that, you can find my UI design below

[image: This is my UI Design]

Your help would be appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Seems like a `9-patch` background.

Comment: use cardView and get benefit of corner radius. then overlap your cardView with other layout

Comment: I'll try this once, Thank you

Comment: That may be an image view.

Comment: The rectangle with the notch is a customview. The size of the notch equal  to the size of the Gpay icon + margin . I am new to customviews and as of now I am not able to cut the notch.

Comment: yeah, something like that, I created a card view with the radius and placed it inside a LinearLayout and below that created another LinearLayout and added color to it, then gave cardview a margin of half of the height of cardview, so cardview went half belo of the LinearLayout, now it looks like a notch!! thanks for @RahulKhurana for sugession

Comment: share a screenshot @rakcode

Comment: better yet post an answer

Comment: yes i'll do it in some time, currently im out

Comment: I did some digging, this is going to require a customview or some use of the [EdgeTreatment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/EdgeTreatment) class. 

The sloution will need some work, IMO if you really want an answer you might have to set up a bounty.

Comment: You could use MotionLayout with some animation adding that view --> https://proandroiddev.com/motionlayout-shapeofview-26a7ab10142f
CardView has only round radius on its corners, its not like the picture you showed from google.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859083/1631967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **cardView** and get benefit of corner radius. then overlap your cardView with other layout

Comment: The shape he is showing requires more then round corners. Where they overlap they need a negative round shape to even out the round corners.