# Android Draw the custom view as in google pay

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

[image: notch image]

This question has already been asked and an answer has been accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648979/how-to-make-a-notch-like-google-pay-in-a-layout) but the accepted answer is not what I am looking for. I want to use a customview in which the notch takes the width  + some margin of the view  which it is going over, like the pay icon in the above image. While looking into the bottomappbar which houses a fab like [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-images-1.medium.com%2Fmax%2F1200%2F1*ofUdXP1U0rjOXcXrcSBnVA.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40lupajz%2Fthe-place-for-bottomappbar-31e0db8f70b1&docid=mPdU0-j7JfgAJM&tbnid=fQB4sCgDKkwG_M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjM1bilx6HfAhVtZN8KHZp3BZcQMwhCKAUwBQ..i&w=1080&h=537&bih=626&biw=1024&q=bottom%20app%20bar%20android%20fab&ved=0ahUKEwjM1bilx6HfAhVtZN8KHZp3BZcQMwhCKAUwBQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)
I saw a class called the [edge treatment class](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/EdgeTreatment) I guess that can be used as well. I am not posting my customview code rightnow as all I could draw is a rectangle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to draw the curves using [`Cubic Bézier Curve`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves). A good article to know how to draw such curves is written by Bartosz Ciechanowski, [here](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/02/18/drawing-bezier-curves/).

[image]

I have developed a `View` to draw a shape like google pay which inherits from `FrameLayout`. The source code is available on [its github repository](https://github.com/aminography/BezierCurveBulgeLayout) (but not documented yet!). However, add the following lines to your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.aminography:beziercurvebulgelayout:1.0.2'
}
```

Then you can use it in `xml` layout files as following:

```
<com.aminography.view.BezierCurveBulgeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bulgeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    app:bulgeType="bulge"
    app:bulgeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:curveWidth="32dp"
    app:flatWidth="56dp"
    app:flatHeight="24dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"/>

</com.aminography.view.BezierCurveBulgeLayout>
```

[image]
.

Its shape and color is customizable to achieve the target shape by changing below attributes:

[image]

Comment: sorry @aminography I mistakenly accepted another answer. Please wait a while I have a old question I will give you your rep there as soon as I can raise the bounty. Right now I seem to be on some type of  cooldown time. Btw do you make tutorials???

Comment: hey @aminography

Comment: would you like to take that bounty on a different question just give a reasonable answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584981/weakhandler-memory-leak

Answer (score 0):

In addition of above answer of @aminography

If anyone looking for answer in java here is the working code in JAVA

> BezierCurveBulgeLayout

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class BezierCurveBulgeLayout extends FrameLayout {

    AttributeSet attrs;
    int defStyleAttr = 0;
    int defStyleRes = 0;

    private int curveWidth;
    private int flatWidth;
    private int flatHeight;
    private int bulgeColor;
    private BulgeType bulgeType;


    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    private Point startCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point startCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point startCurveFirstControlPoint = new Point();
    private Point startCurveSecondControlPoint = new Point();

    private Point endCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point endCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point endCurveFirstControlPoint = new Point();
    private Point endCurveSecondControlPoint = new Point();

    public BezierCurveBulgeLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }


    public BezierCurveBulgeLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.attrs = attrs;

        init();
    }

    public BezierCurveBulgeLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.attrs = attrs;
        this.defStyleAttr = defStyleAttr;
        init();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public BezierCurveBulgeLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.attrs = attrs;
        this.defStyleAttr = defStyleAttr;
        this.defStyleRes = defStyleRes;
        init();
    }


    private void init() {

        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BezierCurveBulgeLayout, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        curveWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.BezierCurveBulgeLayout_curveWidth, 0);
        flatWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.BezierCurveBulgeLayout_flatWidth, 0);
        flatHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.BezierCurveBulgeLayout_flatHeight, 0);
        bulgeType = BulgeType.values()[a.getInt(R.styleable.BezierCurveBulgeLayout_bulgeType, BulgeType.BULGE.ordinal())];
        bulgeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.BezierCurveBulgeLayout_bulgeColor, Color.WHITE);

        a.recycle();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setColor(bulgeColor);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();

        int baseY = 0;
        int flatY = 0;

        if (bulgeType == BulgeType.BULGE) baseY = flatHeight;
        else flatY = flatHeight;


        startCurveStartPoint.set(viewWidth / 2 - flatWidth / 2 - curveWidth * 7 / 6, baseY);
        startCurveEndPoint.set(viewWidth / 2 - flatWidth / 2, flatY);


        endCurveStartPoint.set(viewWidth / 2 + flatWidth / 2, flatY);
        endCurveEndPoint.set(viewWidth / 2 + flatWidth / 2 + curveWidth * 7 / 6, baseY);


        startCurveFirstControlPoint.set(startCurveStartPoint.x + curveWidth * 5 / 8, startCurveStartPoint.y);
        startCurveSecondControlPoint.set(startCurveEndPoint.x - curveWidth / 2, startCurveEndPoint.y);

        endCurveFirstControlPoint.set(endCurveStartPoint.x + curveWidth / 2, endCurveStartPoint.y);
        endCurveSecondControlPoint.set(endCurveEndPoint.x - curveWidth * 5 / 8, endCurveEndPoint.y);

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(0f, baseY);
        path.lineTo((float) startCurveStartPoint.x, (float) startCurveStartPoint.y);

        path.cubicTo(
                (float) startCurveFirstControlPoint.x, (float) startCurveFirstControlPoint.y,
                (float) startCurveSecondControlPoint.x, (float) startCurveSecondControlPoint.y,
                (float) startCurveEndPoint.x, (float) startCurveEndPoint.y
        );

        path.lineTo((float) endCurveStartPoint.x, (float) endCurveStartPoint.y);

        path.cubicTo(
                (float) endCurveFirstControlPoint.x, (float) endCurveFirstControlPoint.y,
                (float) endCurveSecondControlPoint.x, (float) endCurveSecondControlPoint.y,
                (float) endCurveEndPoint.x, (float) endCurveEndPoint.y
        );

        path.lineTo((float) viewWidth, (float) baseY);
        path.lineTo((float) viewWidth, (float) viewHeight);
        path.lineTo(0f, (float) viewHeight);
        path.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    public enum BulgeType {
        BULGE,
        NOTCH
    }

}
```

> attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="BezierCurveBulgeLayout">
        <attr name="curveWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="flatWidth" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="flatHeight" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="bulgeColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="bulgeType" format="enum">
            <enum name="bulge" value="0"/>
            <enum name="notch" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

> Now use like this in your layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00fff7"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <neel.com.demo.BezierCurveBulgeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bulgeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:bulgeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:bulgeType="bulge"
        app:curveWidth="32dp"
        app:flatHeight="20dp"
        app:flatWidth="80dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fav" />

    </neel.com.demo.BezierCurveBulgeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude :) I wrote the library in kotlin, may someone need it in java.

Comment: @aminography yeh thanks and all credit goes to you that;s why i added `In addition of above answer of @aminography` hope it helps to others